# Need help to fetch required data from model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have below two models,

```
class user_files(models.Model):
    Filename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Browse = models.FileField(upload_to='img/')
    user_uploaded = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class share_files(models.Model):
    select_file = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    from_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    select_user = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
```

user_files stores file uploaded by respective user.
and share_files stores shared file name yo user xx by user bb.

I want to show shared files with logged in user in template,

my function for it in view.py is,

```
def user_files_all(request):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'accounts/logout.html')
    else:
            data = user_files.objects.filter(user_uploaded=request.user)
            data1 = share_files.objects.filter(select_user=request.user)
            data2 = user_files.objects.filter(Filename=data1.select_file,user_uploaded=data1.from_user)
            args = {'data': data,'data1':data1}
            return render(request, 'accounts/files.html', args)
```

but i am getting error for line,
             data2 = user_files.objects.filter(Filename=data1.select_file,user_uploaded=data1.from_user)

as attribute select_file is not present for data1. I want data from user_files model for all users and filename selected in data1. And then want to render that in template.

How to achieve that? Need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is because .filter() returns a list of objects. Your data1 is a list of objects so you cannot use data1.select_file. Use something like data1[0].select_file.

Answer (score 0):

`filter(...)` is a model manager method, it returns a queryset instead of an object. So you can do:

Use `first()` or `last()` method after using filter. Because these methods return a object from the queryset:

```
    data_list = user_files.objects.filter(user_uploaded=request.user)
    data1_list = share_files.objects.filter(select_user=request.user)
    if data_list.exists():
         data= data_list.first()
    else:
         data = None

    if data1_list.exists():
        data1 = data1_list.first()
        data2 = user_files.objects.filter(Filename=data1.select_file,user_uploaded=data1.from_user) # its a queryset btw
    else:
        data1 = None
        data2 = None # or user_files.objects.none()
```

Comment: This will probably give error because according to the model there can be more than one `user_files` instances for a particular user. So following `.get()` approach may raise _more_ _than_ _one_ _object_ _found_ error.

Comment: From the user_files model , user_uploaded is shares no relationship with Django User model, which by the way, doesn't seem right to me. As such, this solution will not work as request.user (which is an object) will throw an error when used againt user_uploaded (a string) .

Answer (score 0):

`.filter()` returns a list of objects. So your data1 variable is a list. You cannot just get value of any attribute.

To achieve what you want you could try something like -

```
data2 = []
for d in data1:
   ufs = user_files.objects.filter(Filename=d.select_file,user_uploaded=d.from_user)
   for uf in ufs:
       include = True
       for d2 in data2:
            if d2.pk == uf.pk:
                 include = False
                 break
       if include:
            data2.append(uf)
```

On a side note - your model design does not look good. Consider using ForeignKey. For more refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Hope it helps.

EDIT

If you are using version 1.11 you can use `union()`

```
data2 = []
for d in data1:
    ufs = user_files.objects.filter(Filename=d.select_file,user_uploaded=d.from_user)
    data2 = data2.union(ufs)
```

I haven't tested the above codes but you get the idea. For more info on `union()`, look into [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#union).